# Does set timeout change each expect statement, or just the final expect eof?

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script, expect, unix-utils

I'm learning to use `/usr/bin/expect` for the first time, to automate the nightmare that is installing fink from source, as that script has a few dozen prompts, all of which can be answered with the Enter key. Trouble is, one section of the script takes around 30 minutes, while the last part takes about 10 minutes. I'm not sure whether to `set timeout 1800` or `set timeout 600`. Basically, I want to know whether `set timeout` effects the timeout for every `expect "..."` statement, or if it only affects the final `expect eof`.

I could configure this conservatively and just go with `set timeout 1800`, but I figure if the semantics of expect are about the final eof here, that it is best to select a more specific wait time there.

I know I could also go with `set timeout -1`, but this expect script is to be run by CI servers, and I don't want those to stall indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set timeout` affects the timeout for every `expect` statement. However, you can give an explicit overriding value on any of them:

```
expect -timeout 100 ...
```

Note also that `set timeout` inside a `proc` function will only set it for the local scope of that function, not affecting the global timeout value.